# Life physics: falling objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, everyday-life, free-fall

I've started wondering for a while  WHY we experience so much damage when we hit a ground after a free fall? What forces are responsible for that?

After some thinking I concluded that it has to do with a change of momentum and the heavier the object the greater the force has to act on it to decrease the momentum.

And here came another question. On a falling object acts a gravitational force which is the same during the whole fall. But even if the force is the same, we experience greater damage when it falls upon us than it is put upon us. Is the difference again because of impulse and the force which changes the momentum? If so, do we experience damage because of the force which our body acts on a falling object  to change its momentum?

I need someone to explain me this sort of life problem in details so there will be no doubt what is going on.

Thank you

Comment: Have you done a google search yet?

Comment: Normal reaction from the ground is responsible for the damage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it has do with momentum. momentum  is directly proportional to resultant force applied and is in the direction of the resultant force.

dp/dt = force  where p momentum and t time

when you fall(when you hit the floor) you are stopped immediately (v =0) thus as time taken to change your momentum is low force experienced is high.Now if u fall onto a mattress (a bouncy one) your momentum becomes 0 but it takes much more time thus you experience less force

Comment: fall off a mattress or fall onto a mattress?

Comment: sorry fall onto

Comment: This needs some revision, "Momentum is defined as rate of change of momentum.." clearly momentum is not defined as its own rate of change.

Answer (score 0):

***I've started wondering for a while WHY we experience so much damage when we hit a ground after a free fall? What forces are responsible for that?***

Another way of looking at it in addition to what @Bhavay said, is to apply the work energy theorem. The theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

When an object falls from a height $h$ from the ground, when it reaches the ground its potential energy of $mgh$ is converted to kinetic energy of $\frac{mv^2}{2}$. When it impacts the ground the ground does work to bring the object to a stop. Ignoring the slight change in potential energy after impact, we can say

$$F_{ave}d=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Where $F$ is the average impact force and $d$ is the stopping distance and the product is the work done to stop the object. This may be roughly related to how much damage is done to the ground on impact (other factors may be the conditions of the soil, the geometry of the object, etc.). All other things being equal, the greater the height from which the object falls, the greater the work required to bring it to a stop and therefore the greater the potential damage to the impacted area.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Bhavay's answer, Nothing ever stops immediately. But apart from this, the answer therein and your conclusions in the question are all correct, the force is the change in momentum over time; this gives the impulse.

There is always a crumple zone. When you fall on a floor your knees take up the force over time. Gymnasts will try to do it without any signs of visible bending. That is why they frequently break their ankles. Modern cars are designed with crumple zones. SUVs are designed so that everything else will crumple for you. The bigger the crumple zone, the longer time you get for deceleration, the less change in momentum over time is needed, and thus the less impact force. Parachutists when they land will bend their knees, tuck and roll in order to maximise the distance over which deceleration applies and thus reduce that impact force.

Now damage is a physiological thing. We generally find that it is nonlinear - in this case virtually no damage up to a certain threshold where increasing amounts of force cause damage at a non-proportional increasing rate. But that goes beyond the scope of your question I think.

Now it should be noted that an apple falling on your head has both the impact force and the weight combined.